# Understanding model's learning curves

Tags: cnn, overfitting, regularization

I'm trying to train a Lane Detection CNN called [PINet](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06604) on a proprietary dataset.

**Below are some of the important configuration values:**

- Batch size: 6
- Optimizer: Adam
- Learning rate: High of 1e-4 and Low of 1e-6
- Lr scheduler: Cyclic lr scheduler in triangular mode
- Dropout: 0.5
- weight_decay: 4e-3

**Below is the summary of my dataset:**

- The dataset contains 15200 samples in the train dataset and 2700
  samples in the dev/test dataset.
- For train dataset: 7000/15200 samples come from a stationary scene.
  I.e. 7000 samples display almost exact same scene.

Below you can find the learning curves I have plotted during training [image]

**My questions are:**

1. As per my analysis, The model has achieved an overfit. Am I right
   here?? Looking at the Train/Validation loss what would you say about
   the model fit type??
2. Why my training and validation losses are almost stable (with small
   variation)??
3. What can be done to reduce the training loss even further??
4. What can be done to reduce the gap between Validation and training
   loss?? is it advisable to use dropout values of 0.6 or 0.7 and weight decay as high as 1e-2 to reduce overfitting??

Comment: Seems that your model has stopped learning, which can be improved by decaying the learning rate, increasing the batch size or by applying various regularization techniques ( these may include adding a Dropout layer, Batch Normalization or Early Stopping ).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tested a model from around 230 epochs and 670 epochs. The model from the 670th epoch performs better on the test dataset as compared to the model from the 230th epoch. 
So I'm not sure if the model has stopped learning.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal If you look at current regularization used then would you recommend using even harsh regularization?? such as dropout = 0.6 or 0.7 and weight decay of 1e-2??